# How do I allow user to enter text in terminal *in the middle of the window* in C?

Tags: c, terminal, read-eval-print-loop, getchar

I am looking at something basic like this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
    //scanf("%s", &name);  - deprecated
    fgets(name,20,stdin);
    printf("Hi there, %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

This stops after the first line, and then after you type it prints the second line. I don't want that behavior.

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```
------------------------------------

               Welcome


      Enter email: |
      Enter password:



------------------------------------
```

And the `|` is where the cursor is blinking. When they press enter, it takes them down to the next line the password line. When they press enter from that, perhaps it clears the password and they have to enter it a second time, etc. Then they press enter a final time and it says "Success".

I don't need to know exactly how to implement this, but I would like to know the general strategy so I can figure it out since it's involving a lot of features. I mainly am not sure how I get the cursor positioned properly *in C*. I know about *ansi escape sequences* and how you can position the cursor around. Am I to be doing this in C? Are there any good examples of this that I can reference? What techniques are used to accomplish this?

Comment: another option is to clear and then redraw the entire screen

Comment: Also libslang has API for the screen; another option is to shell to an external command, "tput" (slow but easy).

Comment: Better to avoid ANSI escapes, and use ncurses. No point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can get 'partial' solution, by stripping the '\n' from the end of the prompt, and forcing a fflush(stdout) before the fgets.